# Multiple conditions in SQL joins

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

How to specify multiple conditions in **SQL** joins? I know `A.key = B.key` is mandatory apart from this, is the below correct for specifying multiple conditions in **SQL**?

```
ON (A.key=B.key and/or cond1 and/or cond2 ...etc)
```

**OR**

```
ON (A.key=B.key where cond1 and/or cond2 ..etc)
```

Comment: Just add your conditions to the WHERE part of the clause.

Comment: Don't use the  `where` clause for multiple conditions. A left join would turn into an inner join if you do that. You can define multiple conditions in the `on` clause of a join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first option is correct.

You can use multiple join conditions like:

ON (A.key=B.key and/or cond1 and/or cond2 ...etc).

For the second one, WHERE should come after the ON clause(all the joins using JOIN clause). Then, this will filter the data after the JOIN. Just close the bracket before WHERE, then it will work as well.
Like:

ON (A.key=B.key) WHERE cond1 and/or cond2 ..etc

Both above options can be used, depending upon your requirement.

Answer (score 10):

You can specify as many conditions as you like in the join like:

```
ON A.Key=B.Key
AND b.value>100
AND (a.value>b.value OR b.value2 IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Specify the conditions after the ON condition.

```
SELECT A.ColumnName, B.ColumnName FROM Table1 A <LEFT / RIGHT / INNER JOIN> Table2 B ON
A.Key = B.Key 
AND A.Key > 0 
AND (B.ColumnName <= 10 OR B.ColumnName >= 20)
AND A.Key > B.Key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Column1, B.Column2 FROM Table1 A LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 B ON A.KEY=B.KEY 
AND Condition 1 AND ( Condition 2 OR Condition 3) OR Condition 4
```