# What are valid conditions in SQL for an ON condition in a table join?

Tags: sql, join

What are the possible conditions for an "ON" statement in a SQL table join?

I am not asking for any specific SQL database, just in general. I have searched all over the web, and I can not find anything. All I ever see in documentation and examples is `JOIN ON a.a = b.b`, or sometimes, `JOIN ON a.a != b.b`.

Is it possible to use any operator valid in a `WHERE` clause? For example, are the following valid SQL?

1. `JOIN ON a.a > b.b`
2. `JOIN ON a.a >= b.b`
3. `JOIN ON a.a < b.b`
4. `JOIN ON a.a <= b.b`
5. `JOIN ON a.a IS NOT b.b` (if matching on NULL?)
6. `JOIN ON a.a IS b.b` (if matching on NULL?)
7. `JOIN ON a.a IN ('1', '2', '3')`
8. `JOIN ON a.a IS NULL`
9. `JOIN ON a.a IS NOT NULL`

I found this question on Stack Overflow, which HINTS this might be possible, but I have yet to find a concrete answer to this question anywhere: [Multiple conditions in SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733414/multiple-conditions-in-sql-joins)

Can someone help please? What are valid conditions on a JOIN statement?

Comment: *Is it possible to...* why don't you try and see?

Comment: option 5 and 6 are invalid (you could have found out yourself, when you had tried)

Comment: Most of those are valid in ON _and_ WHERE, but not all of them.

Comment: https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ is handy when checking valid SQL syntax.

Comment: **ANY** valid predicate can be used in an `ON` clause.

Answer (score 3):

The join condition (the part after `ON`) is a boolean expression.

So every valid boolean expression is a valid join condition.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance (I am no SQL pro), but isn't every conditional operator a boolean expression?

Are you saying that all conditional operators are allowed, but things like `JOIN ON a.a IN(SELECT ...)` (a sub-query) are not allowed?

Comment: `x in (select ...)` is valid boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

Every valid boolean expression can be used in a join condition, so that also includes boolean expressions with ANY and ALL.